# What's the best way to include a LIKE clause in a Rails query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

What's the best way to include a LIKE clause in a Rails query i.e. something along the lines of (the completely incorrect):

```
 Question.where(:content => 'LIKE %farming%')
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If this is Rails 3 you can use Arel's `matches`.  This has the advantage of being database agnostic.  For example:

```
Question.where(Question.arel_table[:content].matches("%#{string}%"))
```

This is somewhat clunky, but easily extracted to scopes, e.g.:

```
class Question

  def self.match_scope_condition(col, query)
    arel_table[col].matches("%#{query}%")
  end

  scope :matching, lambda {|*args|
    col, opts = args.shift, args.extract_options!
    op = opts[:operator] || :or
    where args.flatten.map {|query| match_scope_condition(col, query) }.inject(&op)
  }

  scope :matching_content, lambda {|*query|
    matching(:content, *query)
  }
end

Question.matching_content('farming', 'dancing') # farming or dancing
Question.matching_content('farming', 'dancing', :operator => :and) # farming and dancing
Question.matching(:other_column, 'farming', 'dancing') # same thing for a different col
```

Of course to join with "AND" you could just chain the scopes.

Edit: +1 to metawhere and squeel though (haven't tried latter but it looks cool)  They both add this type of functionality and much more.

Comment: Very cool, thank you. I keep reading about Arel but never figured out what it was

Comment: Your scopes are ugly as hell. Use class methods and better arguments lists than this.

Comment: You can add this functionality to all ActiveRecord::Base descendants by putting the above in a file in the config/initializers directory (I also edited names for readability):
module ActiveRecord
  module Querying
    def match_scope_condition(column, query)
      arel_table[column].matches("%#{query}%")
    end

    def matching(*args)
      column_name, opts = args.shift, args.extract_options!
      operator = opts[:operator] || :or
      where(args.flatten.map { |query| match_scope_condition(column_name, query) }.inject(&operator))
    end
  end
end

Answer (score 45):

You'd use the syntax:

```
Question.where("content LIKE ?" , "%#{farming}%")
```

Comment: Thank you just to expand the question, how would you provide an array of conditions to that clause.

Comment: You could do something like this:

`Question.where("content LIKE ? AND name is like ?", "%#{search1}%", "%#{search2}%")`

Comment: Thank you - the answer's so obvious when you write it out!

Comment: Using this raw SQL will only properly work on SQLite and MySQL for case insensitive queries. When working with Postgres (eg. on Heroku), you need to use ILIKE for case insensitive queries, else the LIKE acts as case sensitive.

Comment: This is the best answer when it comes to not including some other library. love it.

Answer (score 9):

If you want really sexy conditions and and don't have problems with external dependencies, I highly recommend [MetaWhere](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_where) and it's successor [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel):

```
# MetaWhere
Question.where(:content.like => '%farming%')

# MetaWhere with operators overloaded
Question.where(:content =~ '%farming%')

# Squeel
Question.where { :content.matches => '%farming%' }

# Squeel with operators overloaded
Question.where { :content =~ '%farming%' }
```

Comment: For Squeel, the correct syntax is `Question.where {content.matches '%farming%'}`