# SQL-like syntax for array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of objects. I need to use an SQL-like condition WHERE field like '%value%' for some object fields in this array.
How to do it?

**Edited:**
For example I have array with `Users` and I need to find all users with `first_name` `like` `ike` and email `like` `123`.

**Edited2:**
I need method to get `Users` with `first_name` like smth and email like smth from **ARRAY** of my `Users`. `Users` have `first_name` and `email`.

**Edited3:**
All my users are in database. But I have some business logic, at the end of this logic I have array with `Users`. Next I need to filter this array with some text: `ike` for `first_name` and `123` for email. How to do it?

Comment: Where do you get that array? Arrays do not have a query language, they are merely containers. Databases often have SQL and if that's the source of your data, then that is where you should apply the query. You could put your array into a database like SQLite, and query it, using the gem Sequel, which is a great ORM and makes it easy.

Comment: We need more info. Describe the attributes of the object. Obviously they must have `first_name` and `email` if you want filter by them, so why can't you use normal Ruby methods to ask them about themselves?

Comment: You have a database. "Next I need to filter this array with some text: ike for first_name and 123 for email." Do that in the database when you request the users, before you do anything else. That is what a SQL query does, it filters to retrieve a subset of an entire database, which is returned to your Ruby code as an array. It sounds like you don't understand how we use databases from a language like Ruby.

Comment: Have you looked at this question on the correct formatting of `LIKE` clauses in Rails queries? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051062/whats-the-best-way-to-include-a-like-clause-in-a-rails-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = %w[hello quick bool boo foo]
arr.select { |x| x.include?("foo") }
=> ["bool", "boo", "foo"]
```

or in your case, if you have an array of objects, you can do:

```
x.first_name.include?("foo") && x.email.include?("123")
```

For more customization, you can use Array#select with [Regexep](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html)s

Answer (score 1):

If you can just use ruby methods for this that do something like this:

```
User = Struct.new(:email, :first_name) # Just creating a cheap User class here

users = [
  User.new('1@a.com'  , 'ike'), 
  User.new('123@a.com', 'bob'), 
  User.new('123@a.com', 'ike'),
]

# results will be an array holding only the last element in users
results =  users.find_all do |user| 
  user.email      =~ /123/ and 
  user.first_name =~ /ike/
end
```

Writing your own sql parser seems like a pretty bad idea, but if you really need to parse simple SQL where clauses you could do something like this:

```
User = Struct.new(:email, :first_name) # Just creating a cheap User class here

users = [
    User.new('1@a.com'  , 'ike'), 
    User.new('123@a.com', 'bob'), 
    User.new('123@a.com', 'ike'),
]

def where(array, sql)
  sql = sql.gsub(/\s+AND\s+/, ' ') # remove AND's

  terms = Hash[ *sql.split(/\s+LIKE\s+| /) ] # turn "a LIKE 'b'" into {'a': "'b'"}

  array.find_all do |item|
    terms.all? do |attribute, matcher|
      matcher = matcher.gsub('%', '.*')         # convert %
      matcher = matcher.gsub(/^['"]|["']$/, '') # strip quotes 

      item.send(attribute) =~ /^#{matcher}$/
    end
  end
end

# results will be an array holding only the last element in users
results = where(users, "first_name LIKE '%ike%' AND email LIKE '%123%'")
```

This will only work for where clauses what only contain `LIKE` statements connected by `AND`'s. Adding support for all valid SQL is left as an exercise for the reader, (or better yet, just left alone).

Answer (score 0):

I've built a ruby gem [uber_array](https://rubygems.org/gems/uber_array) to enable sql-like syntax for arrays of Hashes or Objects you might want to try.

```
require 'uber_array'

# Array of Hash elements with strings as keys
items = [
  { 'name' => 'Jack', 'score' => 999, 'active' => false },
  { 'name' => 'Jake', 'score' => 888, 'active' => true  },
  { 'name' => 'John', 'score' => 777, 'active' => true  }
]

uber_items = UberArray.new(items)

uber_items.where('name' => 'John')
uber_items.where('name' => /Ja/i)
uber_items.like('ja')
uber_items.where('name' => %w(Dave John Tom))
uber_items.where('score' => 999)
uber_items.where('score' => ->(s){s > 900})
uber_items.where('active' => true, 'score' => 800..900)
```